# Adding buttons dynamically to a UIScrollView which changes to fit the number of buttons using Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have an array which loads in a database depending on what button the user chooses.  How can I add these buttons to a scroll view which is only as large as it needs to be to hold all the buttons?  I know I can declare the size of the scroll view, but I don't want it to be too large so that it can fit a large number of buttons then have lots of empty space if a smaller array is used to create less buttons.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you can figure out the vertical height required to display the number of buttons to be displayed before adding them to the scrollview.

If so, at the time of adding a fresh set of buttons, or 'refreshing' the scrollview, I guess you can simply set the correct `contentSize` of the scrollview.

Check the [UIScrollView reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) for `@property(nonatomic) CGSize contentSize`

Comment: This did work.  However, I was just starting out as a developer, and realized it was much more practical to use a tableview

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways . 
Either you can change the frame of the scrollview dynamically

```
myScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, newWidth, newHeight);
```

or you can change the contentSize of the scrollView dynamically keeping the frame constant.

```
  myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight);
```